# Counting elements in a python list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, collections, counter

Suppose I have a list of items, which each of them is a dict like:

`Data = [{ "num": 0, "id": "0001", "text": "Apple" }, { "num": 1, "id": "0002", "text": "Banana"}, { "num": 2, "id": "0001", "text": "Orange" }, { "num": 3, "id": "0001", "text": "Berries" }, { "num": 4, "id": "0002", "text": "Apple" }  ]`

I want a dictionary that counts how many times each id appears in the list. So for the list above the result should be:

`{'0001': 3, '002': 2}`

How can I do this simply in Python?

how can I accessto list of many dictionaries with only one key value?

Answer (score 2):

From a code perspective, the simplest is probably to use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
Data = [{ "num": 0, "id": "0001", "text": "Apple" }, { "num": 1, "id": "0002", "text": "Banana"}, { "num": 2, "id": "0001", "text": "Orange" }, { "num": 3, "id": "0001", "text": "Berries" }, { "num": 4, "id": "0002", "text": "Apple" }  ]
d = Counter([d['id'] for d in Data])
```

Output:

```
Counter({'0001': 3, '0002': 2})
```

Answer (score 1):

Grab the id numbers first in a separate list and then count them:

```
ids = [dct['id'] for dct in Data]
id_counts = {id_num : ids.count(id_num) for id_num in set(ids)}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to loop through the list and check each dictionary individually, although list comprehension is more efficient.

```
result = {}
for dictionary in Data:
    id = dictionary.get("id")
    if id in result:
        result[id] += 1
    else:
        result[id] = 1
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'0001': 3, '0002': 2}
```